# Does an analogue of the sphere theorem hold in higher dimensions?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology, spheres

The *sphere theorem* of Papakyriakopoulos states that if $X$ is a 3-manifold with non-trivial $\pi_2(X)$, then some non-zero element of $\pi_2(X)$ is represented by an *embedding* $\mathbb S^2 \to M$ (rather than just a continuous map).

I was wondering if this generalises beyond three dimensions. It's clear that the result is false for $\pi_n(X^m)$ with $m < n$, but maybe the result is true for $\pi_n(X^{n+1})$?

Going down a dimension, by the classification of 2-manifolds, if $\pi_1(X^2)$ is non-trivial, there is an embedding $\mathbb S^1 \to X$.

I attempted to construct some counterexamples for $\pi_3(X^4)$, but I wasn't sure where to begin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An embedded codimension 1 sphere in a manifold with $H^1(M;\Bbb Z/2) = 0$ (so that every codimension 1 manifold splits $M$ into two components) gives a splitting of your manifold as a connected sum, so if your manifold does not have a non-trivial such splitting then all embedded spheres are null-homotopic. By the resolution of the Poincare conjecture, $S^n \times S^2$ gives a counterexample in dimension $n+2$ for all $n \geq 2$.

Comment: Nice answer!  Do you know what happens if "embedding" is changed to "immersion"?

Comment: Perhaps good to mention is why this is a counter example. It's easy enough to guess why the Poincare conjecture is involved. Because the homology of $S^n \times S^2$ is so small we should deduce that in any splitting, one of the factors must be a homology sphere. But as to why this actually gives a counterexample, that is due to the fact (I don't believe is super well known) that all higher homotopy groups of $S^2$ are nontrivial.

Comment: I tried to work through the details and I can't see why a connected sum necessarily gives a homology sphere. $H_2(S^2 \times S^2)$ is $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$, so I can't figure out how to rule out an expression of $S^2 \times S^2$ as a connected sum of manifolds with second homology $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I should add that while I'm still not sure about the $S^2 \times S^2$ case, for $S^n \times S^2$ with $n \geq 3$, everything seems to work out via Poincare duality.

Answer (score 2):

I can't seem to add details on the other answer so I will do so here.

First, it is not necessary to know that $\pi_{n+1} S^2$ is nonzero --- you just need to know that $\pi_{n+1} S^n$ is, which is either $\Bbb Z$ for $n=2$ or $\Bbb Z/2$ for $n>2$.

Second, let me phrase the cohomology of manifolds in a way that makes it obvious that $S^n \times S^2$ is irreducible. To every compact oriented manifold without boundary is associated a graded group $M^i(X) = H^i(X;\Bbb Z)$ when $0 < i < \dim X$, and zero otherwise; $M$ stands for middle-dimensional cohomology.

Then Poincare duality says that the cup-product pairing is a degree $n$ unimodular perfect pairing $M^*(X) \otimes M^*(X) \to \Bbb Z$. We also know that Mayer-Vietoris shows that $M^*(X \# Y) = M^*(X) \oplus M^*(Y)$, where under this direct sum decomposition the cup product decomposes as $$\smile_{X \# Y} = \smile_X \oplus \smile_Y.$$

So to show that some manifold $X$ is irreducible under connected sum, it will suffice that its intersection form is irreducible under directed sum. But $$M^*(S^2 \times S^n) = \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$$ with cup-form $$\smile_{S^2 \times S^n} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$ It is easily seen that this is irreducible under direct sum: It would need to decompose into the sum of two 1-dimensional forms, in which case one of those forms should take the value `1' on some vector. But $(a,b) \smile (a,b) = 2ab$, which is always even --- so no such decomposition.

---

No idea about immersions. Sounds hard.

Comment: Based on the fact that the geometric design next to your name is different for your two answers, it seems as though you've created two separate accounts. I've let the moderators know - they can probably merge them together for you (if you want).  Welcome to the site!

Comment: If you're interested in regaining access to the other account, consider requesting [the accounts be merged](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). And in that case also consider registering an account; unregistered, cookie-based accounts are less stable — lose the cookie, the account is gone.